# Render a simple list in React with promises

Tags: reactjs, promise

I'm trying to render some content from a service which returns a promise, but I can't figure out how I should return the data in my "return" block.

It's no problem to return some static data, as shown in this example. But how can I return the data from the commented code in the same way?

The image shows the console, where you can see the promise.

I know the answer is probaly very simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

```js
render() {

  const data2 = [
   {title:'item one', id:'000'},
   {title:'item two', id:'001'}
  ];
  console.log(data2);

  const data = firebaseCon.content.get('text', { fields: ['id', 'title'] });
  console.log(data);

  var itemList = data2.map(function(item) {
   return <li className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>;
  });

  return (
   <ul>
    {itemList}
   </ul>
  )
 }
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried `firebaseCon.content.get().then(response=>{console.log(response)});`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will handle the object that is returned by api and also moves the fetching to `componentDidMount`.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      data: [],
   }
}
componentDidMount() {
    firebaseCon.content.get('text', { fields: ['id', 'title'] })
      .then((response) => {
          let data = [];
          for (item in response) {
              data.push(response[item]);
          }
          this.setState({ data });
      });
}

render() {
    let itemList = this.state.data.map(function(item) {
        return <li className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>;
    });
    return (
        <ul>
            {itemList}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

A closer look at Promises' methods `then` and `catch` should make it clearer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: And yeah, as birendra mentions in one of the other answers, it's a bad idea to fetch data in render, better use one of the lifecycle hooks.

Comment: Thanks, you are right I get the .map error - the api returns an Object.. I still can't figure out how to solve this one. Do I have to convert the object to an array, or how can I set it as a new state?

Comment: Hey Martin, I have updated the answer to transform the object to array in the state and also moved the data fetching to the lifecycle hook for better performance.

Comment: Thanks man, I get the expected result rendered now. It all starts to make sense :)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would say that you are doing in wrong way.

You should never make a server request in render function.

You should make a server request in `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()`.

If you know `async/await` concept then it would be helpful for you.

You can check this link..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

You can try like this one...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class ListData extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await firebaseCon.content.get('text', { fields: ['id', 'title'] });
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const itemList = data.map(function(item) {
            return <li className="item" key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>;
        });
    return (
      <div>
        {data.length > 0 &&
           <ul>
             { itemList }
           </ul>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Hope it will be help

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looing for. I know about componentDidMount, but I wanted to keep it simple in the example :) this solution renders data twice tho, first an empty array, and then the array with data, which of course gives an error in the .map. Do you know why it's returned twice?

Comment: Due to component Life Cycle

if you refer the following link then might be help

https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this?

https://github.com/axios/axios

> Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js.

You can see it in action in this tutorial, used with React:

https://codeburst.io/building-appointment-scheduler-app-in-react-and-nodejs-f163c4eaab6b

Hope it helps.